# Can I return global variable from function?

Tags: flutter, dart, global-variables, future

I want to return path String as global variable...I can't use this returned path it says it's dynamic:

```
openGallery(BuildContext context) async {
  var picture = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

  this.setState(() {
    imageFile = picture;
  });

  Navigator.of(context).pop();
  Directory patid = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  String path = patid.path;
  print("$path");
  final File newImage = await imageFile.copy('$path/name.jpg');

  return (path);
}
```

Comment: your function returns void.. Add String before your function.. Also because your function is asynchronous you have to return Future with the String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you function signature to:

```
Future<String> openGallery(BuildContext context) async { //Added return type
  //Your code here...
}
```

and don't forget to call await

```
String path = await openGallery(context);
```

Comment: But it says The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext'.

Comment: You need to pass the BuildContext that is generated on you build function to call this function, note if you have a StetefullWidget you already have by default a global variable context
Be sure that you are typing the context as BuildContext and not Context